# Symfony 4 how to remove form prefix in url

Tags: forms, symfony4

I'm working with symfony 4 and i would like to create a search form. I have this piece of code in my controller :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(array(), array('csrf_protection' => false))
    ->setMethod('GET')
    ->add('q', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => false,
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

But when i submit the form i got this url : `/search?form[q]=hello`

How can i remove the form[] and have this url : `/search?q=hello` without creating a form Type?

In symfony 3 we can use `createNamedBuilder()` but this function was removed.

Thanks.